# Not able to remove first 3 digit of phone number in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the phone number Text-field if you type any number like 919002007805 in the console its print normally but if you want to remove number one by one then up to 9 digits its working fine(919*********) then if you want to remove first 3 digits from input(919) you observe in console its not reflecting ,but in Input its removed ,so  when I want to update the phone number the flag give some unwanted symbol. so how to resolved that one so that in console its working fine at the time of inserting as well deleting time.

```
import React from "react";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";
export default function App() {
  const [fields, setFields] = React.useState([{ value: null }]);
  function handleChange(i, event) {
    if (event) {
      let values = [...fields];
      values[i].value = event;
      setFields((v) => values);
      console.log(`values`, values[0]);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {fields.map((field, idx) => (
        <PhoneInput
          key={idx}
          id="phoneNumbers1"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter phone number "
          value={field.value || ""}
          defaultCountry="IN"
          international
          name="phoneNumbers"
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This could be because you're using a third-party lib in your code, for vanilla react, this should work just fine

Comment: so is there any way by using the 3rd party library to solve that one